# DynamoDB: How to use a query filter to check for conditions in a MAP?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table named "TABLE" in dynamo DB. the rows have a structure like this,

```
{
  "parent_id": {
    "S": "India"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "5164981654811"
  },
  "data_format_version": {
    "N": "2"
  },
  "configuration": {
    "M": {
      "key1": {
        "S": "value1"
      },
      "key2": {
        "S": "[{\"key2Id\":\"Java_x_Python\",\"actions\":\"PUT\"},]"
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, I need to scan dynamo DB to get data if key2 of configuration contains string Python.

Language: Java
can someone please help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DynamoDB Scan with Filter Expression. This document has such examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html

Refer the document below to construct the expression. You can use `contains (path, operand)`.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

Since you are using nested map, your path would be: `configuration.key2`